# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed - java-mysql

Tags: java, mysql

what is the mysql problem ??
I do not know what the error is since I had not used foreign keys before

```
String clientes = "CREATE TABLE clientes("+
                    "ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"+
                    "CUENTA INTEGER,"+
                    "NOMBRE VARCHAR(255),"+
                    "EDAD INTEGER,"+
                    "ADICIONAL INTEGER,"+
                    "DOMICILIO VARCHAR(255),"+
                    "PRIMARY KEY(ID))";

        String cuenta = "CREATE TABLE cuenta("+
                "CUENTA INTEGER,"+
                "SALDOAFAVOR DOUBLE(14,2),"+
                "SALDOENCONTRA DOUBLE(14,2),"+
                "FECHACORTE DATE,"+
                "LIMITECREDITO DOUBLE(14,2),"+
                "FOREIGN KEY(CUENTA) REFERENCES clientes(CUENTA))";
```

Comment: What is error stack trace. Try: FOREIGN KEY(CUENTA) REFERENCES clientes(ID)) in your last line. Because you are not referencing primary key of clientes.

Comment: You need a key on `CUENTA INTEGER` in the first table, unique or otherwise as the case may be. Why are you creating tables via Java?

Comment: [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) is probably right.  See [Examples of Foreign Key Clauses](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#idm140447424655232)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct reference and definition would use the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE cuenta (
    CUENTA INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CLIENTE_ID INT,
    SALDOAFAVOR NUMERIC(14, 2),
    SALDOENCONTRA NUMERIC(14, 2),
    FECHACORTE DATE,
    LIMITECREDITO NUMERIC(14,2),
    FOREIGN KEY(CLIENT_ID) REFERENCES clientes(ID)
);
```

Notes:

- `CUENTA` seems like it should be the primary key of this table.
- The foreign key reference should use the id on `CLIENTES`.
- You don't need `CUENTA` on `CLIENTES`.
- `DOUBLE(14, 2)` is not the right data type.  You want `DECIMAL(14, 2)`/`NUMERIC(14, 2)`.